# Mock/Stub a function (a npm module) with callback using Sinon

Tags: node.js, angular, jasmine, sinon, istanbul

I'm using json2csv npm module to convert the json response to csv format, the code looks like below..

```
json2csv({ data: data, fields: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName'] }, function (err, csv) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(csv);
          }
        });
```

How to stub the above function using sinon so i can write unit tests for success and error scenarios. My unit testing stack is Jasmine and Istanbul.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The getting started for example: http://sinonjs.org/#get-started Has a section on `Stubs`

Comment: @pedromss yes in my other test suites i use sinon.mock and sinon.stub but in this case json2csv is a function and not an object. The mock and stub expects object and method to be passed in but in here i just got a function.

Comment: Post the example usage of your dependency, please.

Comment: This is what exactly i'm trying to do https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562

Comment: You don't need to stub a function. Just pass a dummy one where you need it.